# What is Seaborn's default figure size?

Tags: seaborn

I can find lots of answers of how to *change* Seaborn's figure size. I want to know: what is the default figure size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe seaborn uses matplotlib's default parameters when plotting axes, so you can check the figsize with `matplotlib.rcParams`.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize']
# [12.0, 7.0]

import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="x")
ax.figure.get_size_inches()
# array([12.,  7.])
```

Now for advanced plotting functions that generate figures, this is defined by the function.

For example [`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot), [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot)... have a default parameter of `height=5` (inches) and `aspect=1`, which translates into a figsize of `[5,5]` for a single subplot/facet, and proportionally more for several cols/rows in the [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid%60).

[`pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html#seaborn.pairplot) has a default of `height=2.5` and [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot) of `height=6`.

Comment: How did you find the default height for relplot, displot, etc.?

Comment: @Ryan read the docs or function definition, these are the default parameters.